# Only push changed file/files to artifactory

Tags: bash, shell, artifactory

My current project has this structure:

```
my_libraries
-Library1
 -Library1.csproj
-Library2
 -Library2.csproj
-Library3
 -Library3.csproj
-Library4
 -Library4.csproj
.... and several more
```

Multiple people make changes to these libraries. `my_libraries` is checked into git. Even if one project is changed, all the libraries have to be pushed to our artifactory server. I run a bash script which goes through each folder and make the .csproj file into a Nuget package.

I want to only push the changed project to the artifactory, not all of them each time.

From my research, I am thinking checking if the has of that file changed from last time only then turn it into a Nuget package. How can I do that checking in a bash script? Is that even a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Artifactory's [Deploy Artifact by Checksum](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum) REST API.
It's an optimistic approach. You first calculate the file's checksum and call this API without sending the the file's content. Only if it returns `404` then you use the simple [Deploy Artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) API.

**EDIT:**
An explanation-
Artifactory uses an artifact's checksum (i.e. its sha1 or sha256) to store the content only once in its binary store. Using deploy by checksum is an attempt to use this feature. You sent Artifactory the target path and the checksum you expect the content to have. If there is already an artifact with that checksum, the target path will be created and point to that checksum. The end result is you have the target path with the content, without the need for the content to be sent.
If there is no other artifact with the same checksum, Artifactory responds with `404`. This means that you need to upload the content. So you need to issue another request, but now also sending the content.
If your usecase is that most of the artifacts do not change, this is a good way to speed up up your process and reduce network usage.

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: Thank You for the reply. So as I played around with the hash yesterday, but the `dotnet pack` command gives files different hash each time even if nothing in the content changed.

Comment: Also, sorry I didn't really understand your approach. I would really appreciate if you can explain it. Thank You

Comment: @AliShahbaz Updated with an explanation, but if your artifacts are different each time even though the source has not change, unfortunately  this suggestion won&#39;t help you... Try to see what makes your artifacts have different checksums and disable it.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I was trying to figure out why the hash is different each time but didn't had any luck. However, if I create a nupkg using my script then unpack it to check the .dll file and compare the hash of the dll file to the hash of the dll file in the source(which is a c# proj) they are the same. So I was thinking of pulling down the latest artifact(which is a nuget package), unpack it, cd to the dll file, and comparing it to the dll file that the source has, and if they are same then don't nugetize that project, and move on to do the same with each project.